# Meteor.userId() inside of a Mobx Model

Tags: meteor, mobx, mobx-react

I want to use Meteor.userId() inside of a viewmodel using Mobx for state management.

i.e

```
@observable isLoggedIn = Boolean(Meteor.userId());
```

The issue is, I receive this error when I attempt to do this
"Error running template:

```
`Error: Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls or publications."`
```

I don't believe createContainer is applicable here as it's designed for React components and this is just a standard es6 JS class.

I probably could use createContainer on my main App component and just set the loggedIn observable in an ApplicationModel or something of that sort. But that just feels hacky.

Any ideas or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can wrap it in a function using `Meteor.bindEnvironment`?

Answer (score 0):

Attempt to wrap the entire Meteo class in an persistent observable array:

```
import {observable, toJS} from 'mobx';
import {persist} from 'mobx-persist';

@persist @observable _meteo = Meteo
```

You can then call the state when required by the component:

```
const {_meteo } = props.store

_meteo.userId()
```

..else review the toJS() data!